# bus error with mmap

Tags: linux, mmap

I get bus error (core dumped) when trying to write to memory. I want to  write to a binary file using mmap() and open() functions in Linux. I want to write integers from 1 to 100 in the binary file by mapping it to memory instead of writing to the file directly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define FILE_SIZE 0x100

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

    int fd;
    void *pmap; 

    printf("im here");
    //fd=open(argv[1],O_RDWR|O_CREAT,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
    fd=open("numbers.raw",O_RDWR);

    if(fd == -1)
    {
        perror("open");
        exit(1);
    }

    lseek(fd,FILE_SIZE+1,SEEK_SET); //checking the file length
    lseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET);//points to start of the file

    //create the memory mapping
    pmap = mmap(0,FILE_SIZE,PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,fd,0);



    if(pmap == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        perror("mmap")  ;
        close(fd);
        exit(1);
    }

    close(fd);

    for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
        sprintf(pmap,"%d",i);

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your comment says you are "checking the file length" but you never check the return value of that call. I'd bet it is failing since your file is not large enough, hence the bus error later.
There are multiple other unrelated mistakes in your file as well, by
    the way:

1. Your file size assumes 0x100 bytes are enough to store 100 integers in binary. This is not the case for 64 bit systems.
2. You aren't actually storing binary numbers - you are storing strings of the numbers.
3. You aren't advancing where you write, so you write all the numbers at the start of the file, one on top of the other.

Comment: I have increased the FILE_SIZE to 0xA00 to be on a safer side. For storing binary numbers and for advancing, I've used printf(pmap,"%d\n",i). But I still get the same error.